# How to pars treebank in (python)?

Tags: parsing, nltk

I have several .tree files each file contains more than one tree and I try to pars these file in the easiest way.
when I used

```
 for line in txt.readlines():
```

I faced error in parsing because sometimes line contains two trees
the question is how to separate trees in separated lines?
is there an effiecent solution to solve such problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the corpus reader take care of the segmentation. If the trees are in Treebank format, this might work by itself:

```
from nltk.corpus import BracketParseCorpusReader

reader = BracketParseCorpusReader("path/to/corpus", r".*\.tree")
for sent in reader.parsed_sents():
    print(sent)
```

If this doesn't match your tree format, read [the documentation](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.corpus.reader.html#nltk.corpus.reader.bracket_parse.BracketParseCorpusReader) for the options that customize the input.

Comment: Thanks alexis , it works but sometimes I get this type of exception :Bad tree detected; trying to recover...  Recovered by returning a flat parse.       I want to know the bad tree that detected because , the output of the code  incomplete!

Comment: The bad trees are still there, just without the proper structure. Look through your results for "flat trees" (`tree.height() == 2`).